# .Net Core application refused to connect locally, It throws this site can’t be reached error

Tags: asp.net, .net, asp.net-core, .net-core, localhost

I am not able to run my asp.net core application from visual studio 2019. It was running all good few weeks back but now when I run it, it throws the error as follow:

> This site can’t be reached The connection was reset. Try:
>
> Checking the connection Checking the proxy and the firewall Running
> Windows Network Diagnostics Error: ERR_CONNECTION_RESET

My IIS server is running fine. Just that my local host is refusing to connect.

Have tried updating the visual studio and deleted the .suo file.
Nothing yet worked. I'm stuck on this problem from the last couple of days any lead will be highly appreciated.

[image: Site Can't be reached]

Comment: Which url it is trying to connect to? Please post a screenshot that includes the url. Right now the screenshot tells us nothing.

Comment: @RosdiKasim my bad, I have updated the ss. Please have a look into it.

Comment: @yogesh Ratudi: Try to click on the **Details** button and see the detailed information about the error.

Comment: This is most likely a certificate problem with IIS Express like described here: https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/issues/17939 Running your app med Kestrel profile should work.

Comment: I believe you are trying to connect to https but you are actually running the app on http.